# Connect to dual band 802.11ac in Windows

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dual-band

I have a [TP-Link Archer C7](http://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/cat-5506_Archer-C7.html) router that claims:

> Simultaneous 2.4GHz 450Mbps and 5GHz 1300Mbps connections for 1.75Gbps of total available bandwidth.

I have a [Roswell RNX-AC1300PCE](https://www.rosewill.com/rosewill-rnx-ac1300pce-dual-band-wireless-ac1300-adapter-ieee-802-11ac-n-a-5-ghz-ieee-802-11b-g-n-2-4-ghz-867-mbps-at-5-ghz-400-mbps-at-2-4-ghz-wi-fi-data-rates-pci-e-interface.html) wireless card that claims it can do "867 + 400 Mbps Wireless Speed".

How do I create that connection in Windows 10? On my router the 2.4 and 5 Ghz SSID is different so on Windows it shows up as two different networks. How would I connect to both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A given client can only connect to one band at a time. The marketing practice of advertising AP speed by adding up the max 5GHz bandwidth and the max 2.4GHz bandwidth is misleading since no single client can get that aggregate speed.

Comment: Oh. That is misleading. Thank you for the information. Looks like I wasted my money then.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan I don't think you wasted money unless you only have a single wireless client. You have a high-end client card that can reach 866Mbps and a router that can split its clients over both bands.

Answer (score -1):

To do what you are suggesting you need a feature called mimo or mu-mimo. What it does is aggregate multiple channels together to get you double or triple the WiFi speed.

The bad news is this...to make it work properly both your computer and your router need to be mu-mimo capable. That means they have the antennas necessary to send and receive multiple data streams and the firmware to combine them back together again. Also mu-mimo can send and receive data at the same time rather than changing off between transmit-receive modes. So you need matching hardware. Then you need to hope that your hardware decides to actually use the mu-mimo speeds and not kick you off to a slower speed.

I understand the C7 is a good router and you are probably getting better speeds since it has more channels and bands it can support more clients and give you the best possible speed. But it won’t aggregate the channels.

TP Link has more expensive WiFi Routers and their are better wireless cards supporting mu-mimo, but until mu-mimo is more generally available in Laptops and Routers it might be an expensive Wild Goose chase.

Side Note check out Ubiquiti 802.1ac Access Points.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I guess I misunderstood the way they advertised wireless speeds by saying XXX + YYY. :/

Comment: This is full of bad info. MIMO and MU-MIMO are absolutely not necessary for aggregating channels, and they do not allow the 2.4GHz band and the 5GHz band to be used simultaneously by a single client.

Comment: Alright, point taken. Mu-mimo does not necessarily equal WiFi Network aggregation. Combining two WiFi connections into a faster connection can be done via software or specialized wireless cards. I.e. Speedify However, my point being is that Mu-Mimo is a real router technology and a real laptop antenna technology which in the future will provide blazing fast speeds...channel aggregation or not. Simultaneous send and receive on different channels is very close to aggregating channels but as you point out technically not the same.

Comment: MU-MIMO is *not* “simultaneous send and receive on different channels”, it is simultaneous send to different clients via separate spatial streams. It doesn’t add any speed improvements (like wider channels, more spatial streams, or faster MCSes), it just marginally improves bandwidth usage in certain traffic scenarios.